# undefined method create product/ for nil class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

There're two problems I encountered in the codes below,

1. I was trying to do `@products.each do |product|` but it threw me back `undefined nill class on product` - I've checked the problem in product controller but it's still not defined.
2. when I was trying to create a new product from the simple form for below but it doesn't seem to be saved into the db, is it because the devise issues? (it shows on the url link that authenticate token etc) this is what it shown in the url:

   > http://localhost:3000/products/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=7L5t8CunwqhCGwaCs1L5BXG7WAFBxLE0kbpoDojXeE%2FzzUOPAXVZqXnFRw29OLPD2SsJ%2F%2FHm2EkT0q1qUvxYdQ%3D%3D&product%5Bproduct_name%5D=fvf&product%5Bcondition%5D=dfvd&product%5Bdescription%5D=vdfvdc&commit=Submit

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to:user
  validates :product_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many:products
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  def show
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

```
  <div id='container'>
  <div class='signup_create_product'>
     <form>

<h1>Create a new product</h1>
      <%= simple_form_for @product do |f| %>
       <%= f.input :product_name,
                required: true,
                autofocus: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "product_name" }%>

   <%= f.input :condition,
                required: true,
                autofocus: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "condition" }%>

    <%= f.input :description,
                required: true,
                autofocus: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "description" }%>

         <div class="form-actions">
                <%= f.button :submit, "Submit" %>
              </div>
            <% end %>

     </form>
  </div>
  <div class='whysign'>
    <h1>Share your beloved products with all over the world!</h1>
    <p>This is an Airbnb style platform that you can create your own products and sell it or purchase from all over the world!</p>

    <i class="fas fa-home"></i><%= link_to 'home',root_path  %>


</div>

  </div>
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # [...]
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    # For additional fields in app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])

    # For additional in app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username])
  end
end
```

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    if @product.save
      redirect_to product_path(@product)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update(product_params)
      redirect_to product_path(@cocktail)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    redirect_to products_path
  end

  private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:product_name, :description)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you paste stack trace of error? Which template, what action, which line?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh sure!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what causing issue

```
def show
    @user = User.new
  end
```

remove this from user model and user controller

and in the product controller

```
def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update(product_params)
      redirect_to product_path(@cocktail)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

where do you get the instance variable `@coctail` it should be `@product`

and since you are not permitting condition in product controller i guess you don't need

```
<%= f.input :condition,
                required: true,
                autofocus: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "condition" }%>
```

and update

```
<div id='container'>
  <div class='signup_create_product'>
     <form>

<h1>Create a new product</h1>
      <%= simple_form_for @product do |f| %>
       <%= f.input :product_name,
                required: true,
                autofocus: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "product_name" }%>

   <%= f.input :condition,
                required: true,
                autofocus: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "condition" }%>

    <%= f.input :description,
                required: true,
                autofocus: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "description" }%>

         <div class="form-actions">
                <%= f.button :submit, "Submit" %>
              </div>
            <% end %>

     </form>
  </div>
  <div class='whysign'>
    <h1>Share your beloved products with all over the world!</h1>
    <p>This is an Airbnb style platform that you can create your own products and sell it or purchase from all over the world!</p>

    <i class="fas fa-home"></i><%= link_to 'home',root_path  %>


</div>

  </div>
```

with

```
<div id='container'>
  <div class='signup_create_product'>


<h1>Create a new product</h1>
      <%= simple_form_for @product do |f| %>
       <%= f.input :product_name,
                required: true,
                autofocus: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "product_name" }%>

   <%= f.input :condition,
                required: true,
                autofocus: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "condition" }%>

    <%= f.input :description,
                required: true,
                autofocus: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "description" }%>

         <div class="form-actions">
                <%= f.button :submit, "Submit" %>
              </div>
            <% end %>


  </div>
  <div class='whysign'>
    <h1>Share your beloved products with all over the world!</h1>
    <p>This is an Airbnb style platform that you can create your own products and sell it or purchase from all over the world!</p>

    <i class="fas fa-home"></i><%= link_to 'home',root_path  %>


</div>

  </div>
```

Comment: hi Bhupati thank you so much! so i've get rid of the things thats not needed above and seeded products which are existing now from the codes above, it sitll not showing in the index page as in the products.

Comment: where do you think could be the problems are

Comment: and the reasons why the create new products on product/new is not saving

Comment: hi @hello1234 i have updated please take a look and could you show the index page

Comment: hi @Bhupati just wondering how do i paste code here since there's limit charater.

Comment: so you can edit the original one with the index page

Answer (score 0):

You've got several things going on here, but check carefully and it's likely that the error about "undefined nil class" is about the instance variable `@projects`, not the iteration variable `project`. That is, `@projects` isn't defined (or you've tried to define it and it's not returned any actual records). For example, if you haven't created any projects yet, `Project.all` will obviously return `nil` and so there'll be nothing to iterate over with `each`.

Try using `byebug` to check what's going on in the controller for your index action.

As to your second question, it shouldn't be Devise at issue here because Project isn't a Devise model. But the code you include above has a spurious `<form>` line near the top - this may well be conflicting with the `form_tag` you're creating later on.